# What distribution is used when you make a tensor with torch.Tensor constructor in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I typed and ran `torch.Tensor(2, 3)` in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com). It did work but it returned an weird-valued 2x3 tensor which includes even `nan`.

```
tensor([[3.8202e-36, 0.0000e+00, 3.9236e-44],
        [0.0000e+00,        nan, 1.8750e+00]])
```

I searched [Pytorch(1.7.1)'s `tensor.Tensor` Doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) to find out what distribution the default constructor has but the case when you create a tensor with `Tensor` class constructor was not written.

what happens when you use `Tensor` class constructor and what are the parameters for it?

Comment: The value of an [uninitialized variable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable) is generally unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `torch.Tensor` is identical to the [`torch.empty`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/generated/torch.empty.html#torch.empty) creation operator. It doesn't use a distribution to draw from, it's just a tensor filled with uninitialized values. Essentially used to allocate memory.

```
>>> torch.empty(2, 3)
tensor([[5.5699e-35, 0.0000e+00, 1.5975e-43],
        [1.3873e-43, 1.4574e-43, 6.4460e-44]])
```